# Factorising the Quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The purpose of this question is to gain an explanation and understand the formula and rules factorising the quadratic ${x^2}-7x+12$:

$$
{\begin{align}{x^2}-7x+12 = {x^2}-4x-3x+12\\
                           = x(x-4)-3x+12\\
                           = x(x-4)-3(x-4)\\
                           = (x-4)(x-3)
\end{align}}
$$

looking at the line $= x(x-4)-3(x-4)\\$, the next logical step is to move the $-3$) such that:

$(x-3)(x-4)(x-4)$

**Is there a proof or formula that shows why the common factor $(x-4)$ is dropped to result in?**

$(x-4)(x-3)$

Comment: $$(x-3)(x-4)(x-4)=x^3-11 x^2+40 x-48$$

$$(x - 3) (x - 4)=x^2-7 x+12$$ 

Where did you took the $(x-3)(x-4)(x-4)$ from? From here $ x(x-4)-3(x-4)$ I can think only of using distributivity [$a(b+c)=ab+ac$] to write $(x-4)(x-3)$.

Comment: @Voyska I understand that $(x-3)(x-4)(x-4)$ is incorrect, my question is what are the mathematical rules?  You mention distributivity can you elaborate on this?  I'm refreshing my knowledge filling in the gaps.

Comment: Distributivity is a property of the real numbers, see [here](http://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/RealNumbers/RNProp.html). For college algebra, I guess the factorizating is done in $\Bbb{R}$. But there are a lot of kinds of factorizations using different mathematical ideas, for example: Doing that way, you have $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$, but with modular arithmetic: $(a+b)^2\equiv a^2+b^2 \; (\mod 2)$.

Comment: If you want a *proof* of distributivity, Imagine a rectangle: One of the sides is composed of two measures, if you sum them: $(b+c)$. The other side has one measure $a$. What is the area of the rectangle? $a(b+c)$ Now suppose you separate the rectangle in two parts, you have two new rectangles with area $ab$ and $ac$. Sum them up and they must be the same: $a(b+c)=ab+ac$. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WDpAN.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor isn't dropped, you apply the distribution rule

$$ac-bc=(a-b)c$$

not the "Wonderland" rule

$$ac-bc=(a-b)cc.$$

For instance,

$$4\cdot2-3\cdot2=1\cdot2\ne1\cdot2\cdot2.$$

---

For an intuitive explanation,
$$ac-bc=(\underbrace{c+c+c+\cdots c}_{a\text{ terms}})-(\underbrace{c+c+c+\cdots c}_{b\text{ terms}})=\underbrace{c+c+c+\cdots c}_{a-b\text{ terms}}=(a-b)c.$$

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to where I can read more about the various rules?  I am currently refreshing my Linear Algebra and am filling the gaps in my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You cant simply 'move' the $-3$ with $x$ into a new factor; the first $x$ is being multiplied by the factor  $(x-4)$, and the negative three is being multiplied by by $(x-4)$ too. $(x-3)(x-4)(x-4)$ will result in a third degree polynomial, which isn't quadratic, and so wouldn't make sense as an answer either.

You can use the helpful identity  $[a(b+c)=ab+ac]$ to turn $x(x-4)-3(x-4)$ to $(x-4)(x-3)$, no dropping or 'cancelling' involved.

You could even use the quadratic formula. Use substitution and simplifying to then get an answer of $(x-4)(x-3)$.